# Add all positive values in column

Tags: google-sheets

In MS Excel I can add all positive values in a column with

```
SUMIF(A:A,">0")
```

But this isn't working in the Google Docs Spreadsheets. The `">0"` part is not parsed and gives an error. Is there another method in Google Docs?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`=sumif(A:A, ">0")` works for me in Google Spreadsheet. There is a space between the comma and the first quotation mark.

You can also use `=sumif(A:A; ">0")` with a semicolon instead of a comma.

And without a space works `=sumif(A:A,">0")`

Comment: Just curious, you give the answer with and without a space between the , "  -- is this just a aesthetic thing you do?

Comment: I like using spaces, it's easier for me to read longer formulas

Comment: Thanks, I don't use google spreadsheets, I just wondered =)

Answer (score 0):

It shows error when you include the cell. i.e. If you put formula in cell A1 and you want to take summation till A100, the formula should be `=sumif(A2:A100; ">0")`

Comment: That is because of a circular reference error.